# After putting Windows 10 laptop to sleep, wifi disconnects and cannot reconnect to any networks

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, laptop, sleep

I’ve noticed recently that every time I wake my older laptop (Alienware 15R3) it isn’t automatically connected to my wifi and even if I try to manually search for my wifi no hotspots pop up. Even if I go into the status tab in network settings and click show available networks, nothing appears in the wifi tab. What’s even weirder is that under “network & internet” section in settings the wifi tab doesn’t even show up. I’ve gone into device manager and noticed my usual wireless network adapter device (Killer wireless-n/a/ac 1535) also doesn’t even show up. This is happens whenever I put the laptop into sleep and wake it again. So far restarting is the only fix I’ve found, but I multitask a lot on multiple PCs and require the stuff to be saved over night as well, so it isn’t a viable fix. After restarting everything is back to normal, the adapter shows in the device manager, wifi is in settings, etc.

OS Version: Windows 10 Home 10.0.19041 Build 19041 x64

Network Adapter: Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535 Wireless Network Adapter

BIOS Version(UEFI): Alienware 1.7.0, 2019-01-18

Comment: Install the latest Bios Version, Chipset Driver, Driver for Wifi Controller and Wlan Card Driver from Dell and then test it again.

Comment: Try the following:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator .  Run the following 3 commands in order,  restart and test.   dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup  dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  SFC /SCANNOW

Comment: Did you try to reinstall network drivers ? For example  via Driver Booster

Comment: This is happening with me on Windows 11 on a Surface Pro. All drivers are updated.